# error on after upgrading ruby from 2.3 to 2.4.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, devise-token-auth

I have updated my ruby version for a project and now getting following error. I am using devise token auth for authentication my session creation is working fine and code is still running with older ruby version what I need to do to make it run for ruby 2.4.4

```
/home/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4@opa/gems/fog-xenserver-0.2.3/lib/fog/utilities.rb:4: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated

ArgumentError (key must be 32 bytes):

activesupport (5.0.0) lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:72:in `key='
activesupport (5.0.0) lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:72:in `_encrypt'
activesupport (5.0.0) lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:58:in `encrypt_and_sign'
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:592:in `commit'
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:465:in `[]='
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/cookie_store.rb:117:in `set_cookie'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:353:in `commit_session'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:224:in `context'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:216:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:613:in `call'
activerecord (5.0.0) lib/active_record/migration.rb:552:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:38:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:97:in `__run_callbacks__'
activesupport (5.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:750:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (5.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:90:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:36:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:79:in `call'
better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:59:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:49:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'
railties (5.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
railties (5.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:70:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (5.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (5.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:70:in `tagged'
railties (5.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
sprockets-rails (3.2.0) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
request_store (1.3.2) lib/request_store/middleware.rb:9:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:24:in `call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call`
```

Comment: which version of fog and fog-xenserver you are using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update the Rails to `5.0.1`.

Also I recommend you to update your `fog-xenserver` gem to `1.0.0`:

Gemfile

```
gem 'fog-xenserver', '1.0.0'
```

In the shell:

```
bundle update fog-xenserver
```

Comment: Have you tried to update your Rails version to `5.0.1`?

Comment: you should try it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to upgrade you fog-xenserver to the latest one as this has been fixed. see pull request [Fixnum is deprecated](https://github.com/fog/fog-xenserver/pull/65)

```
gem 'fog-xenserver', '1.0.0'
```

and

```
bundle update fog-xenserver
```

Comment: still same issue Waleed